# Updating the Android USB driver

Tags: android, usb

My USB driver for Android consists of the following files:

[image]

But the Android SDK has the following files:

```
D:\Program Files\Android-SDK\android-sdk-windows\extras\google\usb_driver\i386\WdfCoInstaller01009.dll
D:\Program Files\Android-SDK\android-sdk-windows\extras\google\usb_driver\i386\winusbcoinstaller2.dll
D:\Program Files\Android-SDK\android-sdk-windows\extras\google\usb_driver\i386\WUDFUpdate_01009.dll
```

When I attempt to update the driver to this version, Windows (Vista) says that the latest is already installed and leaves it with the older version. Why can't I update these files? I want to do this because I have a feeling that the older USB driver may be crashing my system.

Comment: What version of vista (32 or 64) are you running? These files (i386) would be 32bit I'd guess.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find a driver specifically for your device and install it manually. It helped me

Comment: I tried to install it manually by first uninstalling the older version and then selecting the directory of the new files but it always installs the older ones.

Comment: Then you have to look for the latest version of drivers. Specify your device, and i hep you.

Comment: My device is a Huawei Y200. But why should that matter? Isn't the Android SDK suppose to provide a generic USB driver to any Android device? Why should the device matter?

Comment: Try this [Driver](http://www.huaweidevice.com/worldwide/downloadCenter.do?method=toDownloadFile&flay=software&softid=Mzk1MzA=). And check is the developer option on your phone is ON

Comment: That is the old driver. When I install it, it just gives me the same files.